# duplicates into a JS Object property becomes 'true' after iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

New to JS object and I just need someone to explain to me, why the object property becomes `true` when adding a duplicate value from an array. Below is my example using `forEach()`or `reduce()` method in removing duplicates. The `undefined`'s makes sense to me. Only the `true`'s, that I don't understand yet.

```
const names = ['James','John', 'James','Bob','John','Steve', 'James']

 let unique = {};
   names.forEach(el => {    
     console.log(unique[el])
    if (!unique[el]) unique[el] = true;    
  });

console.log result inside forEach():
 /*
unique['James'] = undefined
unique['John'] = undefined
unique['James'] = true
unique['Bob'] = undefined
unique['James'] = true
unique['Steve'] = undefined
unique['James'] = true 
*/

console.log(Object.keys(unique)); // [ 'James', 'John', 'Bob', 'Steve' ]
```

Same in using `reduce()`method:

```
Object.keys(names.reduce((a,v) => {
  if(!a[v]) a[v] = true;
  return a;
},{}))

// [ 'James', 'John', 'Bob', 'Steve' ]
```

Comment: Uh, the first iteration of your loop sets  `unique["James"] = true`, so in the third iteration when you're checking `unique["James"]` again it's `true` already… Not certain what else you would expect?

Comment: Btw, in modern JS (i.e. since about 5 years) you'd use a `Set` or `Map` to de-duplicate items

Comment: So, it's like by default that when there is duplicate value, that's already considered ```true```? even though the value is not explicitly defined.(e.g. ```unique.James = true``` or ```unique["James"] = true```

Comment: That's what `unique[el] = true;` does

Comment: Gotcha! it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

firstly it **undefined**, it looks like

1. first circle

> `console.log(unique["James"])` // undefined
>
> `if (!unique["James"]) { unique["James"] = true; }` // it creates { James: true }

2. second circle ("James" already exists)

> `console.log(unique["James"])` // true
>
> // if statement doesn't work

Here are simple examples of solving

```js
const names = ['James','John', 'James','Bob','John','Steve', 'James'];

// example for array
let uniqueArray = [];
for(i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
  if(uniqueArray.indexOf(names[i]) === -1) {
    uniqueArray.push(names[i]);
  }
}
console.log(uniqueArray)


// example for object 
const uniqueObject = {};

names.forEach(el => uniqueObject[el] = true);
console.log(uniqueObject)
uniqueArray = Object.keys(uniqueObject)
console.log(uniqueArray)
```